# issue while trying to run selenium on jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

1,setup jenkins on ubuntu
2,setup selenium on ubuntu
3,create selenium test script
**code as below:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/test/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.yahoo.com')
time.sleep(2)
screenshot=driver.save_screenshot("yahoo.png")
driver.quit()
```

4, success execute script locally
5, trying to use jenkins to run script,
under jenkins build execute shell,
cd /home/test
python test.py
6, Jenkins build failure
**console output:**

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
[test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins127263638261616263.sh
+ cd /home/test
+ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/test/chromedriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

seems webdriver couldn't start, not sure how can i fix this issue and run selenium on jeninks. new to automation, pls advise thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the below on your selenium test script :

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Comment: @yandm are you using a headles chrome if so add also this line below the ones above:
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

Comment: yes, you are awesome!! added this two line, it's work!
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with chromedriver path. Does this path exist on jenkins node "executable_path='/home/test/chromedriver'" ?

Provide the correct path of chromediver which is accessible in jenkins node.

Comment: yes, the path "/home/test/chromedrive" is on jenkins node...